# How to profile a test in Android Studio?

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, profiling, profiler

My Android app has some slow running functionality. A unit test captures it perfectly. The unit test execution shows that it runs way slower than it should be.

Android Studio keeps offering me next to the run method a menu option: "Profile" instead of run. I select that option, but nothing different than run seems to happen. I expected Android Studio to open a window with the timing of all the method calls after the test completes.

[image]

I've searched Google and the Android site. Everything I find talks about profiling in Android Studio in general.

How do I profile an Android unit test? (What does that profile option really do?)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and I decided to investigate a solution because I was thinking that it couldn't be too hard. Boy was I wrong.

My original answer which was never posted contained some awkward fiddling around with `Thread.sleep` and manual timings and hitting the right button at the right time. This was replaced by a more elegant solution using the Debug API from within the code.

Using Android Studio 3.1.3 these were my steps:

- I had to copy my actual unit test into androidTest *(because I actually was interested in algorithmic complexity (and not time consumption) I found no way to actually profile inside Android Studio without an emulator. For performance tests this makes sense but in my case I wanted to ensure that even in complex scenarios my methods behave in a predictable fashion.)*
- To avoid the need of fiddling with with `Thread.sleep` and log output indicating a start/stop you can use combinations of  `Debug.startMethodTracing("File"); or Debug.startMethodTracingSampling() and Debug.stopMethodTracing();` or similar (See https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/generate-trace-logs). My code now looks like

  ```
  @Test
  public void Test_Something() throws Exception
  {
       Debug.startMethodTracing("Predict");
       // DO YOUR CODE
       Debug.stopMethodTracing();

  }
  ```
- When I now execute the profile I can obtain the .trace generated in the mentioned location on the device as stated in the link above:

[image: Trace]

(again read the linked page because you will need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, which my app already had, so it wasn't that much of a hassle in my case.

- Double clicking the trace opens it in Android Studio. Unlike stated at the link above I am currently unable to import such a trace in the profiler because either 3.1.3 lacks this function or I am unable to locate it.
  [image: Trace2]

**Edit**: After I upgraded to Android Studio 3.2 I now can indeed load and save sessions and display them in the Profiler. This has improved a lot. And interesting fact: When I opened the trace in Android Studio 3.1.3 I saw the hit count for methods (how often methods were called) and not their clock times. In the profiler on the other hand I was not yet able to find the call times but instead have access to wall clock times. Would be great if someone has a hint on how to display those too.

Comment: It's better way to save trace file in app's data dir:

    val appContext: Context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()  
    val traceFile = File(appContext.getFilesDir(), "file.trace")  
    Log.w(TAG, "::::: trace file: '${traceFile.path}'")  
    Debug.startMethodTracing(traceFile.path)  

It doesn't need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission